# enable '+python3' failed

Tags: compile-vim

I try to compile vim from source.

First I do

```bash
./configure --with-features=huge \
            --enable-multibyte \
            --enable-python3interp=yes \
            --with-python3-command=/usr/bin/python3.8 \
            --enable-gui=gtk2 \
            --enable-cscope \
            --prefix=/usr/local
```

Then `make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/local/share/vim/vim82` and `sudo make install`, and got no python3 surpport.

Here's output of `gcc --vergion`

```
gcc (Ubuntu 10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04) 10.1.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I check the output of `configure` command

```
checking --with-python3-command argument... /usr/bin/python3.8
checking Python version... (cached) 3.7
checking Python is 3.0 or better... yep
checking Python's abiflags... (cached) m
checking Python's install prefix... (cached) /home/zhiyuan/anaconda3
checking Python's execution prefix... (cached) /home/zhiyuan/anaconda3
(cached) checking Python's configuration directory... (cached) /usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu
(cached) checking Python3's dll name... (cached) libpython3.8.so.1.0
checking if -pthread should be used... yes
checking if compile and link flags for Python 3 are sane... no: PYTHON3 DISABLED
```

It seems that anaconda cause some problem of inconsistency. How to fix this?

Comment: you need the python3 development packages. `--with-python3-command=/usr/bin/python3.8` this one looks also very wrong.  BTW: anaconda might cause problems, try the native python3.

Comment: I use the native python, this is why I use `--with-python3-command`..

Comment: The problem is that `configure` use the cache file, just remove `config.cache` under `src/auto`

Comment: use make dist-clean to get-rid of `config.cache`.